# How to drop rows between two times?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

im doing measurements in a 10min interval every day. Now i want to exclude all measurements during the night. Therefore i extracted the Hour from the Timestamp to be able to exclude all rows/measurements between Hour 22 and 4.
My Dataframe:

| Timestamp | Hour | Measurement1 | Measurement2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-23 03:50:00 | 3.0 | 12.57 | 27.66 |
| 2022-06-23 04:00:00 | 4.0 | 12.78 | 27.89 |

My code:

```
df = df[(df.Hour < 22) | (df.Hour > 4)]
```

But this raises always an TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'float'

Hope for any ideas to make this work.
thank you!

Comment: what is `df.clock`? is it suppose to be `df.Hour`?

Comment: As a general suggestion, please see how to provide a [good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @Roim, sorry, i edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
mask = (df['Timestamp'].dt.hour > 4) & (df['Timestamp'].dt.hour < 22)
df=df[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['Hour'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.hour
df['Hour'] > 4
```

To exclude rows for which the hour is between 22 and 4:

```
df = df[(df.Hour > 4) & (df.Hour < 22)]
```

Note that I am using `&` as the hour needs to be above 4 AND below 22.